# Adding new Constructor C++

Tags: c++

```
DemoApplication::DemoApplication() : BaseApplication("DemoApplication"),
    m_var1(false),
    m_var2(false)
{
........
}
```

Now I need to add one more constructor which has a parameter.

```
DemoApplication::DemoApplication(myParam1)
{
........
}
```

I am getting "No appropriate default constructor available".

Comment: How are you trying to call the constructor(s)? Adding more code to your question would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the error message comes from the constructor definition, it means that one or more of `BaseApplication`, `m_var1` or `m_var2` doesn't have a default constructor, and so needs to be initialised in the constructor's initialiser list, just as you did in the default constructor.

Comment: My bet's on `BaseApplication` indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Construction always starts from the base class. If there are multiple base classes then, it starts from the left most base. (side note: If there is a virtual inheritance then it's given higher preference).

If you have not called your base class's constructor explicitly then default constructor of your base class will be called.

```
DemoApplication::DemoApplication(myParam1)
```

If there is no default constructor in your base class, then it will give you error 'No appropriate default constructor available'.